# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() laravel 6 Using subdomains as language indicators

Tags: php, laravel

I am very new to Laravel and PHP, just trying to adding extra languages to my Laravel website Using subdomains as language indicators.

But getting an error which says 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()'

What am I doing wrong?

**index.blade.php**

```
   <div class="languages">
              @foreach(config()->get('app.locales') as $code => $lang)
                    <a href="http://{{$code}}.localhost">{{ $lang }}</a>
              @endforeach
   </div>
```

**app/Http/Middleware/Language.php**

```
   public function handle($request, Closure $next){
 
    // get the subdomain if exists
    $urlArray = explode('.', parse_url($request->url(), PHP_URL_HOST));
    if (count($urlArray) < 3){
        return $next($request);
    }
    $subdomain = $urlArray[0];
 
 
 
    // if it's the default language: redirect to URL without subdomain
    if ($subdomain == 'en'){
 
        $baseUrl = str_replace('//en.', '//', $request->url());
        return redirect()->to($baseUrl);
 
    }
 
 
 
    // if it's a valid language, set as locale and set time zone
    if ( array_key_exists($subdomain, config()->get('app.locales')) ){
 
        \App::setLocale($subdomain);
         
        setlocale(LC_TIME, $subdomain);
         
    }
 
 
    return $next($request);
 
}
```

**config/app.php**

```
'locale' => 'en',
'locales' => [
    'en' => 'English',
    'de' => 'Deutsch',
    'es' => 'Español'
],
```

Comment: In `php artisan tinker`, do `config()->get('app.locales')`. See if it's spitting out an array. You may just need a `php artisan config:clear` to clear the config cache.

Comment: Yes, it worked "php artisan config:clear"
You saved me
Thank you so so much

Answer (score 0):

Did you try "Config::get('app.locales')"  instead of "config()->get('app.locales')" in foreach loop?

Comment: Laravel 6 documentation suggests the following : `config('app.locales');`